# Iframe takes time to load

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I want to show SmartPHP Calendar in iframe but it take time to load/show.A completely white/bland page shows at start

here is my code

```
<table id="table_1" class="form_table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr><td width="1250" height="950">
<iframe id="myIframe" src="" width="100%" height="950" frameBorder="0"  /></iframe> 
 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#myIframe').attr('src','http://mysite.com/smartphpcalendar/index.php');

});
```

I have two questions

1 -  How i can reduce loading time?

2- How to show loading message/loader image to users not to disappoint and wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you actually wait until the whole site is loaded to only then trigger the loading of the iframes content? You actually force a delay this way.

Instead of triggering the loading from the `$(document).ready...` function simply put the contens url in to the iframe src tag:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" 
        src="http://mysite.com/smartphpcalendar/index.php" 
        width="100%" height="950" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

That way the browser can already start loading the content before the whole page has been setup.

Comment: I read on internet that load it as page is loading..if i use this way,it will load after page loads?correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understand you comment. The way you load it, by using jQueries `$(document).ready()` function means the browser has to load the page, initialize all scripts and the like, and only then you add the iframes target url and the loading can begin. So you load sequentially. Instead I suggest you use the iframes `src` tag directly (the normal way), then the browser can start fetching the url as soon as he sees the iframe definition, regardless of other things have already been loaded and initialized. That should definitely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

As arkascha stated you should be applying the src attribute directly to the html element for faster load times. As far as showing a load screen this can be achieved by overlaying a div on top of the iframe which is removed when the iframe is loaded

HTML

```
<table id="table_1" class="form_table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr><td width="1250" height="950">
 <div id="load_div">LOADING PLEASE WAIT</div>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="" width="100%" height="950" frameBorder="0"  /></iframe> 
 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

JS

```
$('#myIframe').load(function(){ 
    $('#load_div').hide();
});
```

CSS

```
#loading_div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 950px;
}
```